# Rhomobile Rhodes on Windows Mobile 5.0 MC9090G

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes, windows-mobile-5.0

I have deployed Rhodes 3.5.1.13 through Rhosudio (RMS_2.2.1.13) on MC3190 which is Windows Mobile 6.5 and its working fine. For this I have used the following configuration

rhobuild.yml
    cabwiz: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Mobile 6 SDK/Tools/CabWiz"
    vcbuild: "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/vcpackages/vcbuild.exe"

In Run Configurations for Rhodes Application, I have used Platform Windows Mobile 6.0.

Running the same configuration on MC9090G which has Windows Mobile 5.0. The application deployed, but when run the exe file, it says "is not a valid pocket pc application".

What configuration needs to be used to deploy on Windows Mobile 5.0, or is it supported??

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks and regards,
hari.

Answer (score 1):

RhoMobile Suite v2.2 does not support the MC9090. 
This device and other MPA1.0 Motorola Solutions devices will be supported by the forthcoming RhoMobile Suite v4.0, you can find more information on [MSI's developer forum](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-1791).